# `add_to_cart: function(name, price, attr, image_src)` -> how to save php mysql table column / name, price, quantity /

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

```
add_to_cart: function(name, price, attr, image_src) {
            var self = this;

            if (self.settings.product_image) {
                if (self.settings.currency_after_number === 'true') {
                    self.cart.append(
                        '<li class="animated ' + self.settings.animation + '" data-id=' + attr + '>' +
                        '<div class=' + self.settings.cart + '-left>' +
                        '<img src=' + image_src + ' /></div>' +
                        '<div class=' + self.settings.cart + '-body>' +
                        '<span class=' + self.settings.cart + '-name>' + name + '</span>' +
                        '<span class=' + self.settings.cart + '-price>' + price + self.settings.currency + '</span>' +
                        '<input type="number" min="1" value="1" class=' + self.settings.cart + '-input>' +
                        '<button class=' + self.settings.cart + '-remove>&times;</button>' +
                        '</div>' +
                        '</li>');
                }
            }
        }

<button type="button" class="pay_button btn btn-default btn-lg" onclick="ajax_modal()" style="margin-bottom:0px;">
                        <span class="hidden-xs">Save</span>
                    </button>
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Where is you function is being called ?

Comment: add_to_cart: function(name, price, attr, image_src) { var self = this;

Comment: ok if you want to save this cart data in database you have to create php file which save your data.if you want save i can post a test answer

Answer (score 0):

```js
CREATE TABLE `stock` (
  `stock_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `type` longtext,
  `category` longtext,
  `sub_category` longtext,
  `product` longtext,
  `quantity` longtext,
  `rate` longtext,
  `total` longtext,
  `reason_note` longtext,
  `datetime` longtext,
  `sale_id` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `added_by` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `supplier` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `vendor` longtext,
  `user` longtext
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Dumping data for table `stock`
--

INSERT INTO `stock` (`stock_id`, `type`, `category`, `sub_category`, `product`, `quantity`, `rate`, `total`, `reason_note`, `datetime`, `sale_id`, `added_by`, `supplier`, `vendor`, `user`) VALUES
(79, 'add', '1', '29', '129', '11', '150000.00', '1650000', '', '1452488779', NULL, NULL, 0, '0', NULL),
(80, 'add', '1', '43', '135', '12', '60000.00', '720000', '', '1454657480', NULL, NULL, 0, '0', NULL),
(81, 'add', '1', '29', '141', '5', '70000.00', '350000', '', '1454673587', NULL, NULL, 0, '0', NULL),
(83, 'add', '1', '29', '141', '20', '70000.00', '1400000', '', '1471673212', NULL, NULL, 0, '0', NULL),
(194, 'destroy', '1', '29', '160', '2', '8000.00', '16000', '', '1489215981', NULL, '{"type":"vendor","id":"10"}', NULL, NULL, NULL),
(145, 'add', '1', '29', '160', '30', '10000.00', '300000', 'test 30 iig nemlee', '1488775855', NULL, '{"type":"vendor","id":"10"}', 1, NULL, NULL),
(193, 'destroy', '1', '29', '172', '3', NULL, '1', '', '1489215484', NULL, '{"type":"vendor","id":"10"}', NULL, NULL, NULL),
(89, 'add', '1', '29', '139', '20', '10000.00', '200000', '', '1481188978', NULL, NULL, 0, '0', NULL),
(190, 'add', '1', '29', '160', '4', '8000.00', '32000', '', '1489215092', NULL, '{"type":"vendor","id":"10"}', NULL, NULL, NULL),
(191, 'destroy', '1', '29', '160', '4', NULL, '1', '', '1489215154', NULL, '{"type":"vendor","id":"10"}', NULL, NULL, NULL),
(148, 'pos', '1', '29', '160', '30', '10000.00', '300000', 'test 30iig avsan', '1488781432', NULL, '{"type":"vendor","id":"10"}', 1, NULL, NULL),
(192, 'add', '1', '29', '172', '3', '534534.00', '1603602', '', '1489215418', NULL, '{"type":"vendor","id":"10"}', NULL, NULL, NULL),
(122, 'add', '1', '29', '160', '10', '8000.00', '80000', '', '1486895188', NULL, '{"type":"vendor","id":"10"}', 1, NULL, NULL),
(187, 'pos', '1', '29', '160', '10', '10000.00', '100000', '', '1489072207', NULL, '{"type":"vendor","id":"10"}', NULL, NULL, '1'),
(188, 'loan', '1', '29', '160', '22', '10000.00', '220000', '', '1489072855', NULL, '{"type":"vendor","id":"10"}', NULL, '10', NULL),
(189, 'pos', '1', '29', '160', '2', '10000.00', '20000', '', '1489131556', NULL, '{"type":"vendor","id":"10"}', NULL, NULL, '1'),
(151, 'pos', '1', '29', '160', '10', '10000.00', '100000', 'test pos new', '1488825372', NULL, '{"type":"vendor","id":"10"}', NULL, NULL, '1'),
(152, 'add', '1', '29', '160', '10', '10000.00', '100000', 'test 10 new', '1488825417', NULL, '{"type":"vendor","id":"10"}', 1, NULL, NULL);
```

```css
<style type="text/css">
    body {
        background: #f2f2f2;
    }
    li.tgl-menu-btn {
        display: none;
    }
    p.aldaahide {
        display:none;
    }
    .ct-cart-left {
        display: none;
    }
    .ct-cart ol {
        padding-left: 22px;
    }
    .ct-cart li {
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 4px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #EEE;
        list-style-type: none;
    }
    .ct-cart-name {
        float: left;
        margin-left: 8px;
        width: 328px;
    }
    .ct-cart-price {
        float: left;
        width: 130px;
    }
    input.ct-cart-input {
        float: left;
        width: 66px;
        margin-top: -3px;
        margin-right: 115px;
    }
    .image {
        height: 100px;
        overflow: hidden;
        float: left;
        margin-right: 0;
    }
    .inner {
        text-align: left;
    }
    img.ct-product-image {
        width: 150px;
        height: auto;
    }
    button.ct-cart-remove {
        background: url('../template/back/pos/remove.png') no-repeat 0 0;
        font-size: 0;
        border-radius: 0;
    }
    .ct-cart-total {
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        background: #2f343b;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: right;
        color: #FFF;
        font-size: 34px;
        padding-right: 22px;
        padding-top: 8px;
        padding-bottom: 8px;
    }
    /* Grid List-iin CSS */
    .glyphicon { margin-right:5px; }
    .thumbnail
    {
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        padding: 0px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
        -moz-border-radius: 0px;
        border-radius: 0px;
    }
    .ct-product {
        padding: 12px;
    }
    .ct-product.list-group-item
    {
        float: none;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #fff;
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }
    .ct-product.list-group-item:nth-of-type(odd):hover,.ct-product.list-group-item:hover
    {
        background: #f2f2f2;
    }

    .ct-product.list-group-item .list-group-image
    {
        margin-right: 10px;
    }
    .ct-product.list-group-item .thumbnail
    {
        margin-bottom: 0px;
    }
    .ct-product.list-group-item .caption
    {
        padding: 9px 9px 0px 9px;
    }
    .ct-product.list-group-item:nth-of-type(odd)
    {
        
    }

    .ct-product.list-group-item:before, .ct-product.list-group-item:after
    {
        display: table;
        content: " ";
    }

    .ct-product.list-group-item img
    {
        float: left;
        margin-right: 12px;
    }
    .ct-product.list-group-item:after
    {
        clear: both;
    }
    .list-group-item-text
    {
        margin: 0 0 11px;
    }
    a.listgridview {
        border-radius: 0;
        padding: 7px;
    }
    .box-header.with-border {
        border: 0;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
    .list-group-item {
        border: 0;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #EEE;
    }
</style>
```

```html
//Model

<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Pos_model extends CI_Model {
 public function __construct()
 {
  parent::__construct();
 }
 public function getallcategory()
 {
     $q = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM category ORDER BY category_id ASC");

     if($q->num_rows() > 0)
         return $q->result();
     return false;
 }
 public function getallproduct()
 {
     $q = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM product ORDER BY product_id ASC");
     
     if($q->num_rows() > 0)
         return $q->result();
     return false;
 }
}
?>

//Controller

<?php 
if (!defined('BASEPATH')) 
    exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Pos extends CI_Controller {
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();
        $this->load->library('paypal');
        /*cache control*/
        $this->output->set_header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
        $this->output->set_header('Pragma: no-cache');
        $this->crud_model->ip_data();
        $vendor_system   =  $this->db->get_where('general_settings',array('type' => 'vendor_system'))->row()->value;
        if($vendor_system !== 'ok'){
            redirect(base_url(), 'refresh');
        }
    }
    public function index()
    {
     $this->load->model('Pos_model');
     $page_data['system_title'] = "Test";
     $page_data['system_name'] = "Test";
     $page_data['category'] = $this->Pos_model->getallcategory();
     $page_data['product'] = $this->Pos_model->getallproduct();
        $page_data['all_product'] = $this->db->get('product')->result_array();
        $this->load->view('back/vendor/pos/add', $page_data);
    }
}
?>

//View, Select a product is inserted into the cart here
<?php
                    $i=0;
                    foreach($all_product as $row){
                        if($this->crud_model->is_added_by('product',$row['product_id'],$this->session->userdata('vendor_id'))){
                        $i++;
                ?>
                    <div class="ct-product col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-xs-6 shop-items filter-add-product noselect text-center">
                        <a href="#" class="ct-product-button">
                            <div class="image"><img src="<?php echo $this->crud_model->file_view('product',$row['product_id'],'','','thumb','src','multi','one'); ?>" alt="" class="ct-product-image img-responsive"></div>
                            <div class="inner">
                              <span class="ct-product-title title"><?php mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
                                    echo mb_substr(strip_tags($row['title']) ,0, 40); ?>...</span><br>
                              <span data-content="<?php echo $row['sale_price']; ?>" class="price"><b class="ct-product-price"><?php echo $row['sale_price']; ?></b> (<b class="ct-product-quantity"><?php echo $row['current_stock']; ?></b>)</span>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                <?php }} ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

this is pos system,
add_to_cart: function(name, price, attr, image_src) - This function value to save STOCK table column / ' + name + ' = product column, ' + price + self.settings.currency + ' = total column,  + self.settings.cart + = quantity column /

Answer (score 0):

```js
//This is import to card function

add_to_cart: function(name, price, attr, image_src) { var self = this;

 if (self.settings.product_image) {
            if (self.settings.currency_after_number === 'true') {
                self.cart.append(
                    '<li class="animated ' + self.settings.animation + '" data-id=' + attr + '>' +
                    '<div class=' + self.settings.cart + '-left>' +
                    '<img src=' + image_src + ' /></div>' +
                    '<div class=' + self.settings.cart + '-body>' +
                    '<span class=' + self.settings.cart + '-name>' + name + '</span>' +
                    '<span class=' + self.settings.cart + '-price>' + price + self.settings.currency + '</span>' +
                    '<input type="number" min="1" value="1" class=' + self.settings.cart + '-input>' +
                    '<button class=' + self.settings.cart + '-remove>&times;</button>' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '</li>');
            }
        }
    }
```